# rails extract variable from hashie returned from a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rails-console

I'm using a gem called [Desk](http://github.com/zencoder/desk) to return data from desk.com's API.  When I run `Desk.customers(:custom_external_id => temp.id)` it returns a lovely set of data.

I'm looking for the integer 71095620 from `id=71095620`.

```
   => #<Hashie::Rash count=20 page=1 results=[#<Hashie::Rash customer=#<Hashie::Rash addresses=[] custom_external_id="58749" emails=[#<Hashie::Rash email=#<Hashie::Rash created_at="2013-02-13T15:59:26-08:00" email="CENSORED" i
d=33622514 updated_at="2013-02-13T15:59:26-08:00" verified_at=nil>>] first_name="CENSORED" id=68712186 language=nil last_name="CENSORED" phones=[#<Hashie::Rash phone=#<Hashie::Rash created_at="2013-02-13T16:00:45-08:00" id=1301079 phone="CENSORED" updated_at="2013-02-13T16:00:45-08:00">>] twitters=[nil]>>, #<Hashie::Rash customer=#<Hashie::Rash addresses=[] custom_external_id="58749"  emails=[] first_name="CENSORED" id=71095620 language=nil last_name="CENSORED" phones=[] twitters=[nil]>>] total=2>
```

There are obviously multiple id fields all over this and i'm not sure which way is best to extract that integer. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Hasie::Rash readme](https://github.com/tcocca/rash), You can probably do this

```
response = Desk.customers(:custom_external_id => temp.id)
response.results[1].customer.id
```